# GPG key generator does *not* use entropy

Tags: linux, debian, gpg, pgp

I'm trying to generate a GPG key on Ubuntu 16.10 and GPG is taking forever.

I googled a bit and found some websites, including some questions on StackExchange, suggesting to run an entropy generator like `rngd` to help the system generate random numbers faster.

Some of these websites also encouraged to check `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, stating that, on their systems, it reported four-digit numbers before running GPG, and two to one-digit numbers while it was running.

I'm currently running GPG on my computer; it's been running for at least half an hour, and I'm getting this

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail 
3644
```

The number increases over time, and decreases very seldom by small amounts (after writing this sentence it's at 3801). I'm not running any random number generator. Actually, if I try to run one (e.g. `sudo rngd -fr /dev/random`, it drops to around 50; if I use `/dev/urandom` it stays around 3000).

Can anybody help me figure out what the hell is wrong with my system?

I'm on Linux 4.8.0-37-generic, gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15, libgcrypt 1.7.2-beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently after upgrading to Debian 9. Some of the programs that depend on random numbers have had their source code/random generator routines changed in recent Linux versions that make them more dependent on the entropy of the system.

Installing the daemon `haveged` seems to provide a consistent pool of random numbers. So do it:

```
sudo apt-get install haveged
```

The `haveged` daemon is now required by disparate programs requiring entropy, especially in VMs and iOTs (e.g. raspberry, others) where the entropy is normally low.

From `man haveged`:

> NAME
>          `haveged` - Generate random numbers and feed Linux's random device.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          `haveged`  generates  an unpredictable stream of random numbers harvested
>          from the indirect effects of hardware events on hidden processor  state
>          (caches,  branch  predictors, memory translation tables, etc) using the
>          HAVEGE (HArdware Volatile Entropy Gathering and  Expansion)  algorithm.
>          The  algorithm operates in user space, no special privilege is required
>          for file system access to the output stream.
>
> Linux  pools  randomness  for  distribution  by  the  `/dev/random` and
>          `/dev/urandom`  device interfaces. The standard mechanisms of filling the
>          `/dev/random` pool may not be sufficient to meet demand on  systems  with
>          high needs or limited user interaction. In those circumstances, `haveged`
>          may be run as a privileged daemon to fill the `/dev/random` pool whenever
>          the supply of random bits in `/dev/random` falls below the low water mark
>          of the device.